# Can readonly fields be public?

Tags: c#, properties

I've got a class with readonly fields that indicate the state of my object. These fields should be visible from the outside.

At first I showed these fields with `properties` like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly MyState mystate = new MyState();
    public MyState MyState { get { return this.mystate; } }
}
```

But as this is `readonly`, users of my class can't change the instance of the state. Therefore, I removed my `property`, set the `readonly` field as `public` and rename it in Pascal Case.

So far, the only problem I saw was refactoring but as my `public property` is in camel case like my `public readonly`, I can move it into a `property` seamlessly.

Can [Jimmy](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) mess up my object (without modifying the code) or is it more secure to anyway use a `property`?

Comment: The general reasons on why to avoid fields in favour of properties still apply. Even with `readonly`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason not to make it a property; the CLI will typically inline a "get" on such a simple property. It is an extra line of code, of course.

Strictly speaking, changing between field and property is a breaking change. In addition to being a different IL operation, it is also a different semantic, especially if a struct is involved.

Making it a property gives you the best flexibility in terms of changes later; lazy loading, indirection, etc.

Re security: indeed, a readonly field is broadly similar to a get-only property. Both can be equally abused by reflection if someone cares enough to want to do it. My vote would still be on a public property though :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is the beauty of C#: you can use public fields instead of properties, and later change your mind without rewriting the whole project:

```
public readonly MyState mystate = new MyState();
```

And later you can e.g.:

```
private readonly MyState mystate = new MyState();
public MyState MyState { get { someCheck(); return this.mystate; } }
```

Comment: Except when someone's using reflection depending on it being a field (`Type.GetFields()` vs. `Type.GetProperties()`). That's one of the reasons why it's recommended to use properties in the first place.

Comment: Well, in your case you'll have to refactor the code because your `field` is in Camel Case and your `property` is in Pascal Case.

Comment: phg: if your serialization library checks for properties only, or fields only, it desperately needs to be updated :-)

Comment: Marc Gravell: I said "without rewriting your project", so you might have to recompile, but not rewrite (oh, Java, why?).